# Return a concatenated string from a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have executions and each execution has several images, example,

table execution

```
 id |    name
 1   execution1
```

table image

```
id |   executionId | image
1          1          'path'
2          1          'path2'
```

I want a query that get all the executions, with each execution having all their images like,

```
  { executions: [
         { id: 1,
           name: execution1,
           images: 'path+path2'
          },
         {...}
      ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try using a group_concat

```
     select a.name, group_concat(image.image SEPARATOR '+')
     from execution a 
     left join image on image.executionId = a.id
     group by  a.name
```

Comment: You can change to whatever you prefer. But imho this way it will return records even when there is no related data in image table with empty/null value for grouped column, which I would prefer to have if I would develop any application. But that is you answer, you just had no join (typo I guess) at all. Sorry if that disturb you from any point.

Comment: @Alex  You don't disturd ..  .. each time  someone  edit an aswer  for a better version is good.   my comment was for ask if there was somethings i haven't see in question  ,...  i look only at sample provided . without moral  o etichal  (good code / bad code )  evaluation of the code provided  by OP. 
  r